# woocommerce: one action, multiple hooks

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook

is it possible to add one single action to multiple hooks so that the Action can be done in different places?
Specifically speaking, I am coding my woocommerce shop, I want to have a same sidebar in 2 different sections of the page based on the screen size. The default hook is, well, the `woocommerce_sidebar hook`. And when I `add_action` the `woocommerce-get-sidebar` to another hook, it gets removed from the first hook.
Is there any solution or I'm doing in vain?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6688/how-many-times-can-i-hook-into-the-same-action

Comment: thanks , but this is something else.  I want to add One action to Several hooks, not several actions to one hook. Thank you anyway. And, I solved this matter in another way